# How to get class of any element clicked

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get the class (if it is set) of any element that is clicked on the document, is this possible? I have tried:

```
$(document).on('click', function() {            
        var itemClass = $(this).attr('class');          
        if(typeof(itemClass) != "undefined" && itemClass !== null) {
            console.log('The item has class of:' + itemClass);
        } else {
            console.log('undefined or null');   
        }
    });
```

No matter what element I click on, the result in the console is always:
    undefined or null

Comment: Can you make a fiddle? :)

Comment: yes because document doesnot have any class attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [event object](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/)'s [target](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/) property to get the actual element which initiated the event.

The below will get the closest element with class attribute with respect to the clicked element.

```
$(document).on('click', function (e) {

    var itemClass = $(e.target).closest('[class]').attr('class');

    if (typeof (itemClass) != "undefined" && itemClass !== null) {
        console.log('The item has class of:' + itemClass);
    } else {
        console.log('undefined or null');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to use the [`event.target`](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/) property,

```
$(document).on('click', function(e) {
   var itemClass = e.target.className;
   // rest of your code goes here
```

**NOTE:** If there's no class set with the clicked element, then it would return `undefined`.

Comment: sir , u gave Exact same answer like Amit kumar After he answered, still you are getting more +1 ?

Comment: @jQueryAngryBird `After he answered,` what do you mean.? check the posted time of him..

Comment: Oh , my bad , I was thinking " answered 10 min. ago" as "10 min. took to answer" , my bad :) +1.  Dnt know wat happnd to me today.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).on('click', function(e) {
   var itemClass = e.target.className;
    alert(itemClass);
});
```